# Node.JS DNS server; receiving strange strings

Tags: node.js, dns, server

I'm developing a DNS server in Node.js, (yes, maybe it's stupid, but it's just 4 fun). My server is listening on port 53 UDP, and I'm debugging all the data. To try it, I just change my DNS server in the system (Windows) to localhost. And I'm getting strange strings:

[image]

This is my nodeJS server, a simple server that listens on port 53 UDP and outputs all data.

```js
var PORT = 53;
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';

var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('listening', function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
 var StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;
 var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');

 var cent = new Buffer(message);
    val = decoder.write(cent);
    console.log( val);

});

server.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

My question is, is there some way to extract from these strings the URLs?

Answer (score 1):

You're taking DNS wire format data, treating them as if they were UTF-8 encoded strings and printing the result. Since DNS wire format is nowhere close to being string-based (much less UTF-8), this is not very useful. If you want to make sense out of the wire format, you must know how it works and parse it according to its specifications. Start by reading [RFC 1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt).